# Youtube videos appear as black boxes in R-markdown, August 2021

Tags: r, iframe, youtube, r-markdown

I have an R-markdown with youtube video files embedded. In the past, they worked just fine. However, after a recent update to Rstudio, when I knit the markdown the videos appear only as black boxes.

The iframe code is simply:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a-WgKFSEoPs" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The resulting markdown can be seen here: https://tpcovino.github.io/WR696/hydrology/5_met_lab/5_met_lab.html

Did something change in Rstudio that is making the iframe not work any longer? Any thoughts are very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
---
title: "test"
author: "Daniel"
date: "8/6/2021"
output: html_document
---

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a-WgKFSEoPs" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Has this worked before? I also suggest using [rpubs.com](https://rpubs.com) to host RMarkdown documents for testing as well as github

Comment: That produces a black box for me. Does it work for you Daniel? And if so what version of R and Rstudio are you running? Thanks! Tim

Comment: Also, yes. This worked last fall (August/September of 2020) which was the last time I taught this class. Haven't changed the code. Only change that has happened is updates to R/R studio. Code used to work just fine and render playable videos, now it does not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the source, it appears the links are being encoded as data.  In the YAML, setting `self_contained: FALSE` disables this behavior and allows the `iframe` element to be included into the `.html` as written.  To work off of Daniel's answer:

```
---
title: "test"
author: "Daniel"
date: "8/6/2021"
output: 
  html_document:
    self_contained: FALSE
---

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a-WgKFSEoPs" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew - thanks for the input! What I found, and what worked for me was to add data-external = "1", as in:

Comment: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hgPoorCAAGg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen data-external="1"></iframe>

Comment: From what I read online it is some codec issue. But bottom line is the data-external= "1" makes the videos load and work just fine. Thanks!